# В Python по крону не работает ConfigParser

Tags: python

Когда я запускаю скрипт напрямую, либо с помощью командной строки - всё отлично. Когда же я пытаюсь запускать его автоматически с помощью планировщика или утилитки для крона, ConfigParser работает, но он ничего не читает. Он возвращает пустой результат. При попытке запуска на сервере по крону ситуация аналогична. Я боюсь, что там ещё много всего не будет работать, ибо ConfigParser в самом начале скрипта.

Comment: Как указаны пути к конфигурационным файлам?

Comment: Вот начало файла парсера:

import ConfigParser

class Settings():
    def __init__(self, filename='settings.ini'):
        self.parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
...

Я в него ничего не передаю в вызове.

Comment: Вы ведь в кроне перед запуском меняете текущую директорию на нужную, не так ли?

Comment: Так файл настроек лежит в той же директории, что и сам скрипт, который я запускаю. В планировщике вообще не представляю, как можно указать директорию.

Comment: cd script_directory && ./script

Comment: falstaf, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Или права не те под кроном или текущий каталог не тот, как правильно заметили выше.